# constant vs properties in php?

Tags: php

I just don't get it,

```
class MyClass
{
    const constant = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::constant . "\n";
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public $constant = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  $this->constant . "\n";
    }
}
```

Whats the main difference? Its just same as defining vars, isn't it?

Comment: The second example will raise `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` - you have to change `self` to `$this`

Comment: btw sorry for the stupid newbie question. cant hold to not ask it. i mean in python there is just one way of doing a job done. is there any example that constant can do that var cant do ( inside a class ) except the visibility that vars have ? ( eg, protected $var ) .

Comment: "constant?" Ewww. Use "CONSTANT."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Constants are constant (wow, who would have thought of this?) They do *not* require a class instance. Thus, you can write `MyClass::CONSTANT`, e.g. `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. A property on the other hand needs a class, so you would need to write `$obj = new MyClass; $obj->constant`.

Furthermore there are static properties, they don't need an instance either (`MyClass::$constant`). Here again the difference is, that `MyClass::$constant` may be changed, but `MyClass::CONSTANT` may not.)

So, use a constant whenever you have a scalar, non-expression value, that won't be changed. It is faster than a property, it doesn't pollute the property namespace and it is more understandable to anyone who reads your code.

Answer (score 2):

By defining a `const` value inside a class, you make sure it won't be changed intentionally or unintentionally.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if I do `$myClass->constant = "some other value"` (given $myClass is an instance of MyClass) in the latter example, then the value is no longer constant. There you have the difference. The value of a constant can not be changed, because... it is constant.

Comment: and the diffrence with static $var ?

Comment: this confuses the OP more than it answers the question. this is illegal in php: `$myClass->constant = "some other value"`

Comment: Nope, that is fully legal. Everyone ought to understand that $myClass is an instance of MyClass.

Comment: @Adam: You can change the value of a static class variable: `MyClass::$variable = "some new value";`  You can't change the value of a constant.