# ternary operator syntax error in class

Tags: php, class, oop, ternary-operator

I want to use ternary operator to assign two different values to the class variable.

I have following code sample where i am getting fatal error.

```
    class test {
         public $data = (true) ? "working" : "not working"; //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Faltu\test.php on line 15

         function __construct() {
            echo $this->data;
         }  
    }
    $test = new test();
```

I have tried without class and it's working fine but in class I'm getting error.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot have that in the declaration of properties, should be done inside the constructor

Comment: properties have to be declared and, optionally, initialized using a _constant_ value (ie a value known at compile time). 10 seconds on google, or indeed looking at previous questions about ternaries in class definitions should've told you that much

Comment: possible duplicate of [constant vs properties in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590178/constant-vs-properties-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may only assign constant values when declaring properties, you cannot perform logical operations, like a ternary.

You can perform your logic in your `__construct` function:

```
class test {
     public $data = NULL;

     function __construct() {
        $this -> data = true ? "working" : "not working";
        echo $this -> data; // working
     }  
}
$test = new test();
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Comment: without constructor is it possible?

Comment: @Kalpit No, it is not. Logic happens at run-time (when the script is running). At compile-time (when the script is being read and parsed) you can only set constant values (strings, numbers, arrays, etc.).

Comment: @Kalpit its not possible, only inside the constructor. its one of the limitations

Comment: @Kalpit: In a way: when you first use the property, you can use the ternary to set the value on-the-fly, or you can create a getter method that checks if the property has already been set, if not, it can assign a default value. But honestly, you're better off using the constructor. The reason for this limitation is pure logic: class definitions contain a class' initial state, and its working logic, but it can't rely on logic to determine how the class will be defined, so `private static $foo = time()%2 ? 'odd' : 'even';` just doesn't add up: the code is processed @ compile time, not runtime

Comment: So the `time` function needn't be available yet (I even believe I'm right in saying that it isn't, @ compile time)

Answer (score 0):

it works have a look

```
class test {
     public $data = NULL;

     function __construct() {
       echo  $this -> data = true ? "working" : "not working"; //working

     }  
}
$test = new test();
```

Comment: I think it's important to point out that this works because you have moved the ternary operator out of the member variable definition and into the constructor.  It's more than a little useful to explain the reasons why, not just how...